# How do I check all the redirects of a URL and get it as an array?

Tags: php, http, curl, redirect

I'm making a site which checks all the URL redirects, just like wheregoes.com. This site doesn't provide any APIs.

I have to get all redirects, then select the 2nd and 3rd redirect and perform some actions with it. If I use curl I only get the last redirected URL.

I want to get all the URLs redirected like

```
Page 1 -> Page 2 -> Page 3 -> Page 4
```

I want to see the URL of Page 2 and Page 3 then. How can it be done using curl with php or any other way?

The solutions I have found so far are only showing the last URL.

Comment: Have you written any code yet? A simple call to [`get_headers`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) should do the trick

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have Tried All Codes But Only it Shows The Last URL

Comment: @ChrisHaas Also get_headers not works : PHP Warning: get_headers(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /home/LumGpq/prog.php on line 10 PHP Warning: get_headers(http://google.com): failed to open stream:

Comment: Let’s start with your last comment. Instead of your original question, post that comment and say something along the lines of “when I try XYZ, I expect ABC, but I’m getting DEF”. This is something that is usually easier for people to help with.

Comment: What method or crawler library are you using that gives you only the last URL?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller cURL

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice. Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.

Comment: You also need to [edit] your question to show how you are calling cURL.  There are ways of using it to show something other than page 4.  Without seeing your code it is impossible to tell you what you are doing wrong.